# GKE Konnectivity agent error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Our GKE cluster started showing [Konnectivity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/#konnectivity-service) agent errors:

```
connection read failure" err="read tcp 172.16.51.22:49332->172.16.51.8:10250: use of closed network connection" connectionID=1
```

and

```
conn write failure" err="write tcp 172.16.51.22:49332->172.16.51.8:10250: use of closed network connection" connectionID=1
```

and

```
could not read stream" err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = closing transport due to: connection error: desc = \"error reading from server: EOF\", received prior goaway: code: ENHANCE_YOUR_CALM, debug data: \"too_many_pings\
```

These errors appear every 5 minutes and the last error sometimes doesn't show up.

We tried to update GKE cluster to version 1.22.6-gke.300 but it didn't help.

So the question is how do we get rid of this error? Or what could be the cause of the error?

Comment: Please refer to the [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168893/gke-konnectivity-agent-writes-to-closed-connection) which may help to know the cause of the error.

Comment: Did you have time to check my comment? Is your issue resolved? If Yes, please post the resolution steps you have followed as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time to check your comment. I will try to check it out as soon as possible.

Comment: I finally got time to test this solution and it didn't work. I have changed the timeoutSeconds and it did not help.